# AWS cloud watch "Latency" metric and jmeter "Average" metric in summary report for api performance testing

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, testing, jmeter, load

While load/performance testing of API on ELB in AWS using JMeter, I see
AWS cloud watch `Latency metric = 10 ms` (seems good) and in JMeter's Summary Report `Average metric = 3000 ms` (seems bad).

The API returns 1MB of JSON data, but I don't understand why there is so much difference in numbers  and is this api performance acceptable? 
If the SLA said to have 100 ms API response time.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are talking about.  You mentioned ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) but it sounds like you are actually talking about API Gateway.  What is the 100 ms SLA you are referring to?  What do the timestamps in your logs suggest is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking into different metrics:

- **Latency**:  `JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received.`
- **Elapsed time**: JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received.

So Latency is included into response time, it is so-called [Time To First Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) and Elapsed Time is the [Time to Last Byte](https://support.smartbear.com/loadcomplete/docs/testing-with/results/panels/report/response-times/time-to-last-byte.html). My expectation is that you should be sticking to what JMeter reports so you won't be confused with the metrics coming from different sources, JMeter is at least open source therefore you have the confidence regarding how the metrics are calculated.

If response time of 3 seconds is too high you can start looking into the reasons for this which could be:

1. Your API server is simply overloaded, check out CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage using i.e. aforementioned [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
2. Your application configuration might not be ready for high loads. The majority of web/application/database servers defaults are suitable for application development and debugging only (same applies to JMeter) so most probably you will need to tune infrastructure.
3. Your application uses non-optimal algorithms. Use [profiler tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to inspect where it spends time, what are the "heaviest" methods, how long database calls last, etc.
4. Also if your application is behind the ELB JMeter can cache IP address of one of the entry nodes and all your requests will be hitting only one host. To avoid this situation add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan.

References:

- [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)